# Github actions ./gradlew test can't find directory to run unit test

Tags: android, github-actions, workflow

I set up a simple CI work in Github Action for my Android project (Kotlin) that would init unit testing before merging with the master (main) branch

```
on: 
  push: 
    branches: [ master ] 
  pull_request: 
    branches: [ master ]

jobs: 
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build" 
  build: 
    # The type of runner that the job will run on 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job 
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # Setup JAVA
      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      # Execute unit tests
      - name: Unit Test
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew  test
```

But whenever i push any commit into directory, i receive next error which fails Unit tests and block merging:

```
Run chmod +x ./gradlew  test
  chmod +x ./gradlew  test
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    JAVA_HOME_8.0.342_x64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.342/x64
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.342/x64
    JAVA_HOME_8_0_342_X64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk/8.0.342/x64
chmod: cannot access 'test': No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I tried to manually set up a directory with tests using `working-directory: app/src/` but it throws the same type of error.
What I am doing wrong?

Will provide more info on request. Thanks in advance.

ANSWER: To run unit test in pre-merge, you need to set the correct directory, with the   `working-directory:`, In my case it's :

> ./app/src/

Changes in workflow .yaml

```
# List all files (Optional)
  - name: ls
    run: ls -alrth
  - name: add permisiion to gradlew
    run: chmod +x ./gradlew 
    # Execute unit tests
  - name: run unit tests
    working-directory: ./app/src/
    run: chmod +x ./test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make multiple RUN commands to ensure where I am and what is in the current folder:

```yaml
run: pwd
run: ls -alrth
run: chmod +x ./gradlew 
run: chmod +x ./test
```

AS noted by the [OP GremlinShX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10349175/gremlinshx), a `working-directory: ./app/src` was missing.